# Xcode Command Line Tool (XCode 4.6) Run Unit Tests from terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, jenkins, xcode4.6

after many attempts, I didn't figure how I can run unit tests by terminal with a project that is inside a workspace. I tried to create a new Scheme and run that script which builds but doesn't run any tests:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace\ 
           -scheme MyProjectLogicTests\
           -sdk iphonesimulator\ 
           -configuration Debug\ 
           ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO\ 
           TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES\ 
           RUN_APPLICATION_TESTS_WITH_IOS_SIM=YES\ 
           clean build
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also upgrade to Xcode 5, which allows for the command:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme SomeTestScheme -destination "name=iPhone Retina (4-inch)"
```

Note: the destination parameter should match the visible name for the destination you want the test run on.